# autoencoders for anomaly detection, training individual models for different users or roles, how?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoders

Do I first train a generic model for all of my users on a network, say for a network anomaly detection example, then fine tune for each user on their own subset of the training data?  But I'd be using that training data twice then and not sure if that's going to do it or train the generic user, then get a bit more data by letting time elapse and collecting telemetry on the network then fine tune for users on the newly collected data?  The final option would be to just train on individual user data from scratch without any generic user model to fine tune.